# .NET Remoting on Mono: Uri already in use

Tags: c#, .net, mono, .net-remoting

Running:

- Ubuntu 10.04, 32-bit
- Mono 2.6.7

I have an application developed in VS 2008 that uses .NET remoting (with a custom RemotingUDPChannel class). We are trying to run this on linux (building in MonoDevelop) now, but I am receiving the following error.

Code causing exception:

```
this.server = RemotingServices.Marshal(this, objectUri);
```

Exception:

```
System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Uri already in use:
```

We received this error in the past when running on the Window side if we had multiple remoting apps running, but fixed it by creating a new appdomain for each. However, this does not seem to affect it on the linux side. Also, we are not trying to run multiple remoting apps, just the single one.

Any ideas on this problem?  Thanks!

Comment: Is your object URI empty? What's the value for objectUri?

Comment: The URI value is printed in the error message and matches that specified in the config file; I just cut it off of the error message in here.  So it looks like it is getting that value just fine.

Comment: Is the value of your objectUri "RemotingActivationService.rem"? Under Mono 2.6.7 the RemotingServices class by default adds a well known server identity with the URI "RemoteActivationService.rem". If you also use this uri you get the described exception.

Comment: No the value is a custom "name.rem".  I will post our workaround below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Our workaround to this problem:

Remove a tag from our remoting config file that causes the remoting object to be added at both

```
RemotingConfiguration.Configure(configurationFile, false);
```

and

```
RemotingServices.Marshal(this, objectUri);
```

The tag removed was:

```
<service>

   <wellknown mode="Singleton" objectUri="FileSyncer.rem" type="MyLib.FileSyncerServer, MyLib" />

</service>
```

This only had to be done from the server side.

Comment: Thanks for this, solved a stupid problem. Funnily enough, this only happened on Ubuntu/Mono, and not on Win7/.NET